# how can I upload my files to show my question better

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask my questions by uploading my files to mean my questions, better. But, I can't upload my files. How can I upload my examples file under my questions on this site?

Thank you very much in deed

Comment: What type of files do you want to attach?  Only images are supported (max 2 MiB), otherwise you'd need to upload the file somewhere else and post a link.

Comment: Note that questions on SE sites should contain all relevant data in the question. Your files may give 'additional' information or test data, but the question should be answerable without those files. You can maybe include the first few rows in your question (if it's data).

Comment: thank you very much in deeed